# Deploying a python app with wheels instead of requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I have a number of python packages defined in requirements.txt and instead of installing from external sources would like to package/install them from wheels.

I ran the following command to generate the wheels from my requirements.txt based on docs[1](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installing-from-wheels):

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

However, the docs then state "And then to install those requirements just using your local directory of wheels (and not from PyPI):"

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=/local/wheels -r requirements.txt
```

I have two questions:

1. I have a lot of wheels after running the first command, is there a way to package all of these requirements into one wheel
2. Why do I have to specify requirements.txt in the second command, is there no way for pip to install all the wheels it finds in the /local/wheels directory